# Game Maker Studio 2 LOCAL multiplayer

Tags: bluetooth, multiplayer, wifi-direct, game-maker, gml

I want to make a simple multiplayer game with Game Maker Studio 2 for mobile platforms, but it should work locally (via wi-fi or bluetooth).
For e.g. [this is a list](https://sites.google.com/site/androidmultiplayergames/home) of existing games and my game will be classified as (Bluetooth | WIFI Direct | Online).
I have some experience in programming and GML should not be a problem for me.
But I want to know for sure whether it is possible to implement Wi-Fi Direct and bluetooth communication?
Required answer those who have already done it. Any plug-ins required for this? 
I do not want to reinvent the wheel and modify some libraries or broken code.  I just need a 100% working solution.

Why Game Maker Studio 2? Because I want to make a game with my friend who doesn't have any programming skills. So, we need some game editor like Game Maker Studio 2 despite the fact that I have programming experience. And now my task - is to solve the problem with local multiplayer before we start to make a game. Maybe there are other editors that fit these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Gamemaker has some built-in functions to make a local multiplayer (I assume it is what you mean by "WiFi"). if you are familiar with UDP/TCP, it's a plus. They can be found here :
https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/networking/index.html

I personally used them for a local multiplayer and it worked fine.

For the bluetooth, the devs are working on some functions, but I believe they didn't release them yet.

If you want to make a global multiplayer, you have to face a few tehnical issues (port forwarding, global matchmaking, etc.) I recommand GMnet, that comes in two flavors :

- GMnet Punch if you simply want to communicate through a NAT with your own synchronisation strategy.
- GMnet Engine if you don't want to worry about the details and let them do all the work for you.

The official website : https://gmnet-engine.org/engine/

Keep im mind that for a global matchmaking, you will probably need some kind of relay server, so that players can find the games hosted by other players. It is not that hard and GMnet comes with a java server program for this purpose, but it needs to be hosted on a server with direct internet access (no NAT).

Hope it was helpful !